# Load Javascript file on function call

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, recaptcha

I'm using **Google Captcha** when some number of login attempts failed, my website is based on `Ajax and Java Script` so I need to load **Google Captcha** `Java Script` file when a function called!

I'm getting captcha code through making a request to my API, `http://www.myserver.com/api/?request=captcha` so this will return

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LeV3rdSAAAAABp2Q3bjyjCR9E6vvZ06oM6-6yj"></script>`

I use `$POST` to make the request and `.HTML` to show captcha on my site

```
$.post("api/index.php", {request: "captcha"}, function(data) {

    $('#customContent').html(data);
});
```

but this doesn't show up captcha on the HTML element! Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does the Google recaptha script use `document.write()` to insert it's content?  If so, you can't insert that afterwards as it won't work.  `document.write()` will only insert things into the current location in the document if it runs while the page is loading.  Otherwise, `document.write()` clears the current document and starts a new one.

Comment: Have you checked to see if there is a response to your AJAX call? Are you sure this response is coming back as plain text and not JSON?

Comment: @DevlshOne yes, I checked the response! its same as above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [this Google page](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) and follow the instructions for dynamically inserting Google captcha into a page.  You must do it differently than you are.  If you're going to fetch the code with ajax, then scroll down the above page until the section labeled AJAX API and follow their code example.

You should read their directions exactly, but basically you put this in your page all the time:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
```

You create a container div for where you want the captcha to go and give it an id and then you call this with your key and the id when you want to insert the captcha:

```
Recaptcha.create("your_public_key",
    "element_id",
    {
      theme: "red",
      callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
    }
  );
```

FYI, I've never done this myself.  I just Googled and read instructions.

Comment: Yes it works, after posting this question here, I also start Goggling more and found the same answer! thanks mate..

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found an answer myself and thanks for your answers!

```
function showRecaptcha() {
        Recaptcha.create("your public key", 'captchadiv', {
        tabindex: 1,
        callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field
        });
}
```

and you don't need to `load` Google Captcha **Java Script at the begging** just use `getScript` function to load Google Captcha script when maximum failed logging attempts occurred and use `.done` responce status to call `showRecaptcha()` function. good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Don't use jQuery to put script tag that uses document.write, instead put it with native javascript, like:

```
$.post("api/index.php", {request: "captcha"}, function(data) {

    $('#customContent')[0].appendChild(data);
});
```

I hope it helps!